# how to get the value of dynamically created <p>

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclicklistener

I am creating multiple `<p></p>` elements dynamically in jquery.

```
var output = '<p>' + results.length + ' matches found</p>';
$.each(results, function (index, result) {
        output += '<p class="'+result.text+'">- ' + result.text + '</p>';
 });
$('#search-output').html(output);
```

Now when i click on the `<p>` elements i want the text value. I tried like

```
 $('#search-output').click(function(e){
        var data= $(this).text();
        console.log(data);
        $("#output").text(data);
    })
```

But then all the contents of #search-output is showing. I want to get the value of the `<p>` I clicked. any help

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Read about [`Event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$('#search-output').on('click', 'p', function(e){
    var data= $(this).text();
    console.log(data);
    $("#output").text(data);
});
```

Comment: @Subho, I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically create elements you need to edit jquery code and **fire click event on body** something like this

```
 $('body').on('click','#search-output p',function(e){
    var data= $(this).text();
    console.log(data);
    $("#output").text(data);
})
```